# Here Mobile SDK PositionSimulator

Tags: android, here-api

I'm using Here Mobile Android SDK and try to simulate GPX track, in order to test my map behaviour. I use `PositionSimulator` class, set callback for position updates, but when I call `startPlayback(filename)` it parse my gpx files with no errors on android, but not simulate fake gps coordinates.

Can someone provide a workable gpx file for PositionSimulator or workable code sample?

My code:

```
posManager = PositioningManager.getInstance();
posManager.start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK);
posManager.addListener(
   new WeakReference<PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener>(positionListener));
mapFragment.getPositionIndicator().setVisible(true);
simulator = new PositionSimulator();
PositionSimulator.PlaybackError err = simulator.startPlayback(trackFileName);
```

simulator instance received correct number of points, but my location marker and camera don't move at all. I try different gpx files with routes, waypoints and tracks. Maybe I need to setup a timestamps inside gpx somehow? Permissions for Moc locations added.

Is there any better way to test camera movements, when simulating driving among some route? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below you can see example of the gpx, which can be played by `PositionSimulator`:

```
<gpx>
  <metadata>
   <name>london</name>
   <time>2017-01-19T17:41:11Z</time>
  </metadata>
<trk>
  <name>test</name>
<trkseg>
  <trkpt lat="51.47785480" lon="-0.14754295">
    <ele>8.0000000</ele>
    <time>2010-01-01T00:00:00Z</time>
    <hdop>33</hdop></trkpt>
  <trkpt lat="51.47788554" lon="-0.14778173">
    <ele>8.0000000</ele>
    <time>2010-01-01T00:00:01Z</time>
    <hdop>42</hdop></trkpt>
  <trkpt lat="51.47787976" lon="-0.14807005">
    <ele>6.0000000</ele>
    <time>2010-01-01T00:00:02Z</time>
    <hdop>20</hdop></trkpt>
....
</trkseg>
</trk>
</gpx>
```

The only one thing I did wrong was not providing hdop field - value for accuracy. Even if you turn off the accuracy displayments for PositionIndicator - apparently it will not be played without that `hdop` value.

AndrewJC, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your app in the "Settings > Developer Options > Select mock location app" dialog? [More info](http://www.phonearena.com/news/Heres-how-to-easily-fake-your-GPS-location-on-Android_id62775)

Also, you can try troubleshooting by using the `PositionSimulator` `getPositionCount`, `getCurrentPositionIndex` and `getPosition` APIs to see if it seems to be handling your GPX log properly.

You can try creating a GPX log using the HERE SDK by using the `PositioningManager` `setLogType` API with `LogType#DATA_SOURCE`

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm already done all that. Settings set correct. checked total points count and its content - it's correct (as I mentiod before), only location is not appearing and moving. When I wrote logs by SDK into gpx, and played it - marker just moved to last position at log. How do I need to setup timestamps in logs (or do something else), in order to simulate smooth position updates like when I driving?

Comment: Would you be able to provide the logs you are trying to use (e.g. through dropbox for example)? Based on the details you have provide so far it appears it should be working.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I finally figured it out) GPX didn't play by HERE Mobile SDK, if it does not has **hdop** field. Even if I hide accuracy displaying on PositionIndicator.

Comment: @AndreySuvorov I see, thanks for reporting back and glad you got it working